# Printing the text when checkbox is clicked

Tags: java, swing, javax.swing.text

I have a doubt regarding Swing application. In this image, if the check box is checked and next button is clicked, it need to show the printed text in the next frame as "enter the movie name". Could anyone please help me with this?

## Code:

```
private void nextActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){


 if (movie.isSelected()== true ){

    // code 

 }
else

{
    // code

  }

}
```

What code I need to write to show the text as "enter the movie name:______" in the same window when next button is clicked
Image:

[image: here]

Comment: Can you post some code that you have already tried ?

Comment: Printing is quite unclear here.It seems like you are are looking for passing value from one frame to other .

Comment: private void nextActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){


 if (movie.isSelected()== true ){
    
 // code 

 else{
    // code

}



What code I need to write to show the text as "enter the movie name:______" in the same window 
when next button is clicked.

Comment: Use a `CardLayout`. Switch to a panel with the new contents.

Answer (score -1):

In this panel you can make a textfield invisible.
When you clicked button the textfield will enable for input Movie name